# symfony mapping error : inverse and owning side field field doesnot exist - even though I declared them in both the classes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I followed the symfony doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata) to create bidirectional relationship between two class `partgroup(OneToMany)` and `partsub(ManyToOne)`

I get this error message when I try to validate the doctrine schema

```
* The association Test\MyBundle\Entity\SpareParts\OemPartPosSubText#partgrpidk refers to the inverse side field Test\MyBundle\Entity\SpareParts\OemPartPosGrpText#partgrpidk which is not defined as association.

* The association Test\MyBundle\Entity\SpareParts\OemPartPosSubText#partgrpidk refers to the inverse side field Test\MyBundle\Entity\SpareParts\OemPartPosGrpText#partgrpidk which does not exist.
```

And

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Test\MyBundle\Entity\SpareParts\OemPartPosGrpText' mapping is invalid:
* The association Test\MyBundle\Entity\SpareParts\OemPartPosGrpText#partsubidk refers to the owning side field Test\MyBundle\Entity\SpareParts\OemPartPosSubText#partsubidk which is not defined as association, but as field.
```

[Code](https://gist.github.com/gghhh456/09d89babda2cb5a0968d)

I tried `cache:clear`

I have looked everywhere stackholder and google  but could not find any resolution.

Comment: Could you show us your entities? Only with relevant associations, no need to copy them completely.

Comment: okay i updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mappings are not correct. Proper mappings should be something like this:

```
/**
 * OemPartPosGrpText
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="oem_PartPosGrpText")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\MyBundle\Entity\SpareParts\Repo\SparePartMenuRepository")
 *
 */
class OemPartPosGrpText
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="PartGrpIDK", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $partgrpidk;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="partSubText", mappedBy="partgrp")
     */
    private $partsubs;

    ...


/**
 * oemPartPosSubText
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="oem_PartPosSubText")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\MyBundle\Entity\SpareParts\Repo\SparePartMenuRepository")
 */

 class partSubText
 {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="PartSubIDK", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $partsubidk;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManytoOne(targetEntity="OemPartPosGrpText",inversedBy="partsubs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="PartGrpIDK", referencedColumnName="PartGrpIDK")
     */
    private $partgrp;

    ...
```

(I also modified your property names)